# C++/g++ cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to *.exe.stackdump

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, cygwin

Here's my main in Airport.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Airport_Queue.h"
#include "Airplane.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    Airplane *b = new Airplane(true);
    (*b).come();
    (*b).go();
    std::cout << "........." << std::endl;
    Airport_Queue *landing_queue = new Airport_Queue(5);
    Airplane *a0 = new Airplane(true);
    (*landing_queue).enqueue(a0); //error here
    //(*landing_queue).dequeue();

return 0;
```

This is my Airport_Queue.cpp

```
#include "Airport_Queue.h"
Airport_Queue::Airport_Queue(unsigned n){
    Airplane** a = new Airplane*[n];
    capacity = n;
    size = 0;
    head = tail = 0;
}
Airport_Queue::~Airport_Queue(){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        delete a[i];
    }
    delete [] a;
}
void Airport_Queue::enqueue(Airplane* airplane){
    if (!(*this).isFull()){
        a[tail] = airplane;
        (*a[tail]).come();
        tail = (tail+1) % capacity;
        size++;
    }
    else{
        std::cerr << "Queue is full." << std::endl;
    }
}
Airplane* Airport_Queue::dequeue(){ 
    if (!(*this).isEmpty()){
        size_t x = head;
        (*a[head]).go();
        head = (head+1) % capacity;
        size--;
        return a[x];
    }
    else{
        std::cerr << "Queue is empty." << std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }   
}
bool Airport_Queue::isEmpty(){
    if (size == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
bool Airport_Queue::isFull(){
    if (size == capacity)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
int Airport_Queue::getSize(){
    return size;
}
```

I also have a class called Airplane. The command I use to compile and link is
`g++ -std=c+11 -Wall -g -o airport Airport.cpp Airplane.cpp  Airport_Queue.cpp`
How can I fix this run-time error? The error is when I call `enqueue`. Then I get

4 [main] airport 3796 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to airport.exe.stackdump

Please. And thank you.

Comment: Don't do that to your post. When you read my answer, it won't make sense any more. What you should do is (1) Keep the original code and then add the updated code at the bottom, or (2) Create a completely new post with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

1. You have one member variable `size`. You need two - `capacity` and `size`.
2. In `Airport_Queue::Airport_Queue`

   ```
   Airport_Queue::Airport_Queue(unsigned size){
       Airplane** a = new Airplane*[size];
       size = 0; // This is the argument, not the member variable.
                 // The member variable remains uninitialized.
       head = tail = 0;
   }
   ```

   You need:

   ```
   Airport_Queue::Airport_Queue(unsigned size){
       Airplane** a = new Airplane*[size];
       this->capacity = size;
       this->size = 0;            
       head = tail = 0;
   }
   ```
3. In `Airport_Queue::~Airport_Queue`

   ```
   Airport_Queue::~Airport_Queue(){
       for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(a); i++){
           // sizeof(a) does not give you the number of elements
           // in the array. It just gives you the size of the pointer.
           delete a[i];
       }
       delete [] a;
   }
   ```

You need:

```
    Airport_Queue::~Airport_Queue(){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < this->size; i++){
            delete a[i];
        }
        delete [] a;
    }
```

1. In `Airport_Queue::enqueue`

   Following on the logic from the destructor, the following line needs to be changed.

   ```
   tail = (tail+1) % sizeof(a);
   ```

   Change it to:

   ```
   tail = (tail+1) % capacity;
   ```
2. In In `Airport_Queue::dequeue`

   You have an error similar to the above. Change the line

   ```
   head = (head+1) % sizeof(a);
   ```

   to

   ```
   head = (head+1) % capacity;
   ```
3. In `Airport_Queue::isFull`

   Change the line

   ```
   if (size == sizeof(a))
   ```

   to

   ```
   if (size == capacity)
   ```

I hope this fixes most of your problems. If there are any that I missed, hopefully you can find them.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed all that but still have the same error. I'll update the code in the post so you can see.